# Change.call is not working with bind-able property

Tags: javascript, console, dropdown, aurelia, bindable

I have one bind-able property which I have to use in drop-down to analyze which ID is selected.
I am using change.call method to identify when user will select drop-down options then console will give selected id.

On options selections change.call is giving random ID on same option .

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Yes. It's unclear how you are using it. Did you mean listen to change event? or simply passing the call back to bindable `change` of dropdown? either case, please help us help you :)